# Blazor Server Side - real-time update with StateHasChanged Loop

Tags: c#, blazor

At the moment I use an infinite loop (with a delay) on my Blazor server page to update my UI.

```
<div>
    @for (int i = 0; i < GlobalData.Length; i++)
    {
        @GlobalData[i]
    }
<div>

@code {

    public CancellationTokenSource CancellationTokenSource { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        RealTimeUpdate(CancellationTokenSource.Token);
    }

    public async Task RealTimeUpdate(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while(!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000 / 60), cancellationToken);
            if(!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                InvokeAsync(() => this.StateHasChanged());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So sure that works fine for my local environment with a single session.  But how would this perform under load out in the wild?

Comment: IMO it's look fine for blazor server app, because it's use SignalR

Comment: You should use `ConfigureAwait(false)` : `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1000 / 60), cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);`

Comment: Can you explain the case of use of your code? It's a game loop or something like this? I use it on Flappy Blazor Bird: https://github.com/ctrl-alt-d/FlappyBlazorBird/blob/master/src/FlappyBlazorBird/FlappyBlazorBird.Client/Data/Universe.cs#L42 but refreshing each user UI via event.

Comment: @aguafrommars there is no `SynchronizationContext`, so `ConfigureAwait(false)` won't make any difference.

Comment: This loop does nothing and we can't see how it's called. Both are important for a meaningful answer.

Comment: @daniherrera nice game!  Yes it is like a game loop.  Basically I have a Global market book (level 2) and each page is just a view of that constantly updating data.

Comment: @SörenKuklau https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/ has a good article on why ConfigureAwait(false) *does* make a difference even without any synchronization context.

Comment: Side note: `1000 / 60` is 16. You want `1000.0 / 60.0`, or at least `1000 / 60.0`. No need for 1000 milliseconds either, that's just one second. I would write it as `const int fps = 60; TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0 / fps);`

Comment: Another side note: Your game will not run at 60fps with this code, unless your code in between the 16ms wait periods is running instantaneously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

StateHasChanged, whether on server or browser, will rerender the current component/page and all of its children (etc).

The result is rendered to a virtual DOM in memory, and then compared to the virtual DOM of the previous render. If anything has changed, it will generate a delta of html for the client to render.

So the answer is, it may send very little html to the browser, but the server will be rendering pages in memory for every user 60 times per second.

That's not going to scale well at all. You'd be much better off using a Reactive library for pushing data from your source to your UI. That way it will only render when needed, and your UI will update immediately.

See https://blazor-university.com/overview/blazor-hosting-models/

And https://blazor-university.com/components/render-trees/

Comment: actually looks like a prime candidate for Roland Pheasant's excellent [DynamicData](https://github.com/reactiveui/DynamicData) library, which was built for exactly this purpose.